# ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1)

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, jboss7.x, ejb-3.1

I try to run an ear and i have this error :

> 12:20:47,649 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner]
>   (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation
>   failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2"
>   => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"earCargaison.ear\".\"CargaisonWeb.war\".POST_MODULE"
>   => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"earCargaison.ear\".\"CargaisonWeb.war\".POST_MODULE:
>   Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment
>   \"CargaisonWeb.war\" of deployment \"earCargaison.ear\""},"JBAS014771:
>   Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" =>
>   ["jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.GLN.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.GLNMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.GLN.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.GLN]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Publicite.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.PubliciteMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Publicite.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Publicite]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.paiement.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.paiementMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.paiement.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.paiement]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.TransportCat.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.TransportCatMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.TransportCat.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.TransportCat]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.SubCategorie.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.SubCategorieMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.SubCategorie.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.SubCategorie]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.SubCategorie.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.SubCategorieMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.SubCategorie.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.SubCategorie]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.DEV.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.DEVMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.DEV.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.DEV]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Feedback.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.FeedbackMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Feedback.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Feedback]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Help.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.HelpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Help.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Help]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.BanqueService.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.BanqueServiceMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.BanqueService.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.BanqueService]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.GLN.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.GLNMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.GLN.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.GLN]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Offre.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.OffreMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Offre.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Offre]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Langue.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.LangueMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Langue.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Langue]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Message.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.MessageMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Message.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Message]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.continent.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.continentMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.continent.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.continent]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Message.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.MessageMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Message.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Message]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Nouvelle.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.NouvelleMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Nouvelle.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Nouvelle]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.TransportCat.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.TransportCatMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.TransportCat.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.TransportCat]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Vat.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.VatMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Vat.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Vat]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.StatutLivraison.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.StatutLivraisonMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.StatutLivraison.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.StatutLivraison]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Vue.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.VueMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Vue.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Vue]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.An.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.AnMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.An.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.An]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.BK.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.BKMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.BK.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.BK]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.BanqueService.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.BanqueServiceMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.BanqueService.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.BanqueService]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Declaration.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.DeclarationMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Declaration.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Declaration]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Declaration.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.DeclarationMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Declaration.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Declaration]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.CAt.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.CAtMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.CAt.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.CAt]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.ParamApplication.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.ParamApplicationMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.ParamApplication.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.ParamApplication]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.BK.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.BKMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.BK.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.BK]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Publicite.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.PubliciteMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Publicite.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Publicite]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Transport.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.TransportMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Transport.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Transport]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Cms.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.CmsMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Cms.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Cms]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.CIMP.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.CIMPMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.CIMP.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.CIMP]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.DEV.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.DEVMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.DEV.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.DEV]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.ImageSite.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.ImageSiteMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.ImageSite.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.ImageSite]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.GeolocalisationEJBImpl.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.GeolocalisationEJBImplMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.GeolocalisationEJBImpl.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.GeolocalisationEJBImpl]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.GeolocalisationEJBImpl.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.GeolocalisationEJBImplMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.GeolocalisationEJBImpl.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.GeolocalisationEJBImpl]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Contact.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.ContactMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Contact.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Contact]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Nouvelle.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.NouvelleMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Nouvelle.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Nouvelle]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Help.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.HelpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Help.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Help]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Etat.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.EtatMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Etat.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.earCargaison.CargaisonEJB.Etat]"]}}}

my file persistence.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd ">
<persistence-unit name="PU_Cargaison"  transaction-type="JTA">
<jta-data-source>java:/dsCargaison/</jta-data-source>
<properties>
<property name="hibernate.dialect"   value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and the file standalone.xml is :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
```

```
<extensions>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.configadmin"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jdr"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.mail"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.osgi"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.pojo"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.sar"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.threads"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.web"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/>
</extensions>

<management>
    <security-realms>
        <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
            <authentication>
                <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authentication>
        </security-realm>
        <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
            <authentication>
                <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authentication>
        </security-realm>
    </security-realms>
    <management-interfaces>
        <native-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
            <socket-binding native="management-native"/>
        </native-interface>
        <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
            <socket-binding http="management-http"/>
        </http-interface>
    </management-interfaces>
</management>

<profile>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE">
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb.config">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:configadmin:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
        <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
                <driver>h2</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>sa</user-name>
                    <password>sa</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:/dsCargaison" pool-name="dsCargaison" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cargaison</connection-url>
                <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                <driver>mysql</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>root</user-name>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                    <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                </validation>
                <statement>
                    <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                </statement>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql"/>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
        <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:1.2">
        <session-bean>
            <stateless>
                <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/>
            </stateless>
            <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="simple"/>
            <singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/>
        </session-bean>
        <pools>
            <bean-instance-pools>
                <strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                <strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
            </bean-instance-pools>
        </pools>
        <caches>
            <cache name="simple" aliases="NoPassivationCache"/>
            <cache name="passivating" passivation-store-ref="file" aliases="SimpleStatefulCache"/>
        </caches>
        <passivation-stores>
            <file-passivation-store name="file"/>
        </passivation-stores>
        <async thread-pool-name="default"/>
        <timer-service thread-pool-name="default">
            <data-store path="timer-service-data" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
        </timer-service>
        <remote connector-ref="remoting-connector" thread-pool-name="default"/>
        <thread-pools>
            <thread-pool name="default">
                <max-threads count="10"/>
                <keepalive-time time="100" unit="milliseconds"/>
            </thread-pool>
        </thread-pools>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:1.2" default-cache-container="hibernate">
        <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query">
            <local-cache name="entity">
                <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="local-query">
                <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="timestamps">
                <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                <eviction strategy="NONE"/>
            </local-cache>
        </cache-container>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:1.1">
        <archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-error="true" fail-on-warn="false"/>
        <bean-validation enabled="true"/>
        <default-workmanager>
            <short-running-threads>
                <core-threads count="50"/>
                <queue-length count="50"/>
                <max-threads count="50"/>
                <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
            </short-running-threads>
            <long-running-threads>
                <core-threads count="50"/>
                <queue-length count="50"/>
                <max-threads count="50"/>
                <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
            </long-running-threads>
        </default-workmanager>
        <cached-connection-manager/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jdr:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.1">
        <show-model value="true"/>
        <remoting-connector/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.0">
        <jpa default-datasource=""/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:1.0">
        <mail-session jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
            <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>
        </mail-session>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.1"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:osgi:1.2" activation="lazy">
        <properties>
            <property name="org.osgi.framework.startlevel.beginning">
                1
            </property>
        </properties>
        <capabilities>
            <capability name="javax.servlet.api:v25"/>
            <capability name="javax.transaction.api"/>
            <capability name="org.apache.felix.log" startlevel="1"/>
            <capability name="org.jboss.osgi.logging" startlevel="1"/>
            <capability name="org.apache.felix.configadmin" startlevel="1"/>
            <capability name="org.jboss.as.osgi.configadmin" startlevel="1"/>
        </capabilities>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:pojo:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:1.1">
        <connector name="remoting-connector" socket-binding="remoting" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:sar:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.1">
        <security-domains>
            <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                    </login-module>
                    <login-module code="RealmUsersRoles" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="usersProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/application-users.properties"/>
                        <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/application-roles.properties"/>
                        <module-option name="realm" value="ApplicationRealm"/>
                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">
                <authorization>
                    <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">
                <authorization>
                    <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-domain>
        </security-domains>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:threads:1.1"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:1.1">
        <core-environment>
            <process-id>
                <uuid/>
            </process-id>
        </core-environment>
        <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>
        <coordinator-environment default-timeout="300"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
        <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
        <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
            <alias name="localhost"/>
            <alias name="example.com"/>
        </virtual-server>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.1">
        <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
        <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>
        <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
        <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
            <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
                <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
            </pre-handler-chain>
        </endpoint-config>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:1.0"/>
</profile>
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
    <socket-binding name="osgi-http" interface="management" port="8090"/>
    <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it seems that your web application cannot reference your EJB's.

Could you please paste your application.xml and web.xml file. As well as the source code of one of the EJB's that are failing to deploy.